# sequentially reading a text file in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

In C++, I want to sequentially read word from a text file, and store each word into an array? After that, I will perform some operation on this array. But I do not know how to handle the first phase: sequentially reading word from a text file and store each word into an array.
I should skip those punctuations, which include ".", ",", "?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like homework. If it is, please be forthright.

First of all, it's almost always a bad idea in C++ to use a raw array -- using a vector is a much better idea. As for your question about punctuation -- that's up to your customer, but my inclination is to separate on whitespace.

Anyway, here's an easy way to do it that takes advantage of `operator>>(istream&, string&)` separating on whitespace by default.

```
ifstream infile("/path/to/file.txt");
vector<string> words;
copy(istream_iterator<string>(file), istream_iterator<string>(), back_inserter(words));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use streams for this. Take a look at the examples here: 
[Input/Output with files](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete program that reads words from a file named "filename", stores them in a `std::vector` and removes punctuation from the words.

```
#include <algorithm>  // iostream, vector, iterator, fstream, string

struct is_punct {
    bool operator()(char c) const {
        static const std::string punct(",.:;!?");
        return punct.find(c) != std::string::npos;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream in("filename");
    std::vector<std::string> vec((std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in)),
                                 std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
    std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                   vec.begin(),
                   [](std::string s) {
                       s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), is_punct()),
                               s.end());
                       return s;
                   });
    // manipulate vec
}
```

Comment: You'll need to compile it with a compiler that understands C++0x lambdas. If your compiler doesn't understand lambdas then replace the lambda with a plain functor. In fact, I think I'd do that anyway. :p

Comment: Indeed. Don't write C++0x in production code; the syntax may be unlikely to change much now but it's not standard yet, and support for it is still experimental!

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how many words you'll be reading?  If not, you'll need to grow the array as you read more and more words.  The easiest way to do that is to use a standard container that does it for you: `std::vector`.  Reading words separated by whitespace is easy as it's the default behavior of `std::ifstream::operator>>`.  Removing punctuation marks requires some extra work, so we'll get to that later.

The basic workflow for reading words from a file goes like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::string w;
    std::ifstream file("words.txt");  // opens the file for reading

    while (file >> w)  // read one word from the file, stops at end-of-file
    {
        // do some work here to remove punctuation marks            
        words.push_back(w);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Assuming you're doing homework here, the real key is learning how to remove the punctuation marks from `w` before adding it to the vector.  I would look into the following concepts to help you:

- The [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Erase-Remove).  Note that a `std::string` behaves like a container of `char`.
- [`std::remove_if`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/remove_if.html)
- The `ispunct` function in the [`cctype`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/) library

Feel free to post more questions if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another possibility, using (my usual) a special facet:

```
class my_ctype : public std::ctype<char> {
public:
    mask const *get_table() { 
        // this copies the "classic" table used by <ctype.h>:
        static std::vector<std::ctype<char>::mask> 
            table(classic_table(), classic_table()+table_size);

        // Anything we want to separate tokens, we mark its spot in the table as 'space'.
        table[','] = (mask)space;
        table['.'] = (mask)space;
        table['?'] = (mask)space;

        // and return a pointer to the table:
        return &table[0];
    }
    my_ctype(size_t refs=0) : std::ctype<char>(get_table(), false, refs) { }
};
```

Using that, reading the words is pretty easy:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    std::ifstream infile(argv[1]);   // open the file.

    infile.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new my_ctype());  // use our classifier

    // Create a vector containing the words from the file:
    std::vector<std::string> words(
        (std::istream_iterator<std::string>(infile)),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>());

    // and now we're ready to process the words in the vector
    // though it might be worth considering using `std::transform`, to take
    // the input from the file and process it directly.
```

Comment: Nice, using facets seems to be very elegant. However, my system gives me a 0 for std::ctype<char>::classic_table(). Any idea?